# Want to show $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}*n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

Want to show $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}*n}$ converges. I am trying to show this by showing that the partial sums are bounded. I have tried doing this by induction but am not seeing how to pass the inductive assumption part. Do I need to instead look for a closed form? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum is less than $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** All the terms are postive and $$\frac{1}{n2^n}\leq \frac 1 {2^n}$$

Think about the monotone convergence, or the so called comparison test.

**Spoiler**

> The partial sums are bounded above, and are monotone increasing, thus the monotone convergence theorem implies convergence.

Comment: *hadn't seen =P

Answer (score 5):

You might want to realize a general principle here.

If we have $$\sum_{a \le n \le b}\frac{1}{f(n)g(n)}$$ and $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are positive on $[a,b]$, then we always have that $$\sum_{a \le n \le b}\frac{1}{f(n)g(n)}\le\sum_{a\le n\le b}\frac{1}{f(n)} \text{ and } \sum_{a \le n \le b}\frac{1}{f(n)g(n)}\le\sum_{a \le n \le b}\frac{1}{g(n)}$$ when the sums $$\sum_{a \le n \le b}\frac{1}{f(n)}$$ and $$\sum_{a \le n \le b}\frac{1}{g(n)}$$ both converge.

In our case, we have that only one converges. Thus, only one of the inequalities is true.

Comment: "positive" $\mapsto$ "$\ge 1$".  Also, you are describing finite sums, so there is never any question of convergence (boundedness, sure).

Comment: Nite approach +1

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Try using the ***[root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#The_test)***. ${}{}{}$ This will give you that the series converges.

You need only know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[\large n]{n} = 1.\quad$ Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[\large n]{\dfrac{1}{n2^n}} = \sqrt[\large n]{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\sqrt[\large n]{\frac{1}{2^n}} = 1 \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} < 1 \implies \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\cdot2^{n}}\quad \text{converges}.$$

Note also that you'd get the same result (that the series converges), by using the the ***[ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test)***.  Both the root test and ratio test are very useful for establishing convergence and/or divergence of many series.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned induction:

Let $s_m = \sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1}{2^{n}*n}$. Then $s_m \leq 1-\frac{1}{m}$.

$P(2)$ is obvious, while $P(m) \Rightarrow P(m+1)$ reduces to

$$1-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2^{m+1}(m+1)} \leq 1- \frac{1}{m+1}$$

which is equivalent to:

$$m \leq 2^{m+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Or we can go this way
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^{n}}\le\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1$$
and the sum is precisely $\log 2-\frac{1}{2}$ (hint: use the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-x), |x|<1)$

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the Cauchy test for convergence of a sequence.

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k2^k}$.

If $m < n$,
$S_n-S_m = \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{k2^k}
< \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^k}
< \frac{1}{2^m}
$
and this $\to 0$
as $m \to \infty$.

Therefore the sequence converges.

Comment: How do you know that the last inequality is true?

Comment: Is induction required on n and m to show that?

Comment: No, only the observation I make in my answer.

Comment: sorry to get back to this late, but i mean the portion" $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac {1}{2^{k}} < \frac{1}{2^{m}}$"

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $-\ln(1-x)=\sum_1^\infty {x^n \over n}$ for $-1\le x<1$. Hence the series in question converges to $\ln{2}$.